# Difference between search and nameserver in resolv.conf

Tags: dns

I am confused about setting my `resolv.conf`.

What is the difference between search [DNS server] and nameserver [DNS server]

Do both of those refer to the DNS server?

Comment: You mark a question as answered by clicking on the small tick under the answer, not by changing the title as SOLVED.

Comment: Click the white check button under the answer to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search defines which domains shall be searched for partial computer names. Nameserver defines which servers shall be queried.
See:http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf

Comment: Please flag the question as answered